# What's the point of pataphysics

Tags: history-of-philosophy

It doesn't seem serious, and many consider it not to be serious. However, at the same time, there are institutes for it. Isn't that like having a department for silly talk?

Comment: Could you expand a little on it? What is "patophysics"? Why are you interested in it? ...

Comment: Why assume that something has to be serious to be worthwile ?

Answer (score 1):

Pataphysics can be considered an outgrowth of Dada, an art movement that occured after the second world war, when the avant-garde essentially inverted enlightment values as they accused it of leading Western civilisation into the holocaust that was the second world war.

Its the excessive focus on the rational without imagination or human values that they are satirising. Its the same point that Andre Breton made in his manifesto on Surrealism. They're not against science per se, but science gone awol.

Satire is the key word. But perhaps satire once institutionalised loses its satirical edge...